# Should I delete an answer with inappropriate comments?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I answered [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18392/when-do-we-get-co-ed-showers). I thought I was giving a reasonable explanation of why modesty standards evolve. This was misunderstood and the following comments are getting off the track.

Is it appropriate to delete my own answer in such a case?

Who would still see it?

Comment: I guess you can. You can try to improve your own answer to make clarify your point of view. But at the end of the day, the comments are getting out of track, not your answer.

Answer (score 5):

(I've only had time for a quick glance so far.)

If your answer is good -- it answers the question, it's not just a one-liner, it doesn't have major problems, it's been well-received, etc -- then please don't delete an *answer* just because of the *comments* it's attracted.  That would be throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

If you see problematic comments -- rude, too chatty, whole conversations unfolding therein, tangents, etc -- please flag.  Moderators can and do delete comments (quite a few; we're a chatty bunch here on Worldbuilding).  But don't rely on us to notice; this is a large, active site and new comments don't alert most people.

If comments point out issues in your answer -- things that aren't clear, errors, logical problems, etc -- then you should *edit the answer* to account for this input.  Once you've done so those comments are probably obsolete, so you can flag them as such.  A meaningful edit comment will help us evaluate the obsolescence of those comments when we see the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Other than clarifying your answer on that particular question, I don't think you need to delete it.  The comment thread on your answer look like an [threadnaught](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=threadnaught) to me so I wouldn't worry about it.